# How to write calculation in php form without entering mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php-7

I have a problem with calculation when using the function. I want the total spending limit and annual balance directly calculate without entering SQL and the only annualspendinglimit retrieve from SQL. the annual spending limit is additional data of txtcost which is inserted into the treatment table. It successfully inserts into the database but it doesn't display totalspendinglimit and annual balance.

```
<?php               
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))    
{
    if(empty($_POST['txtdate']))
    {
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="-1">Fill in date</font></p>';
    }
    else
        if(empty($_POST['txtcost'])){
            echo '<p><font color="red" size="-1">Fill in cost</font></p>';
        }
        else {              
                        
            if($annualspendinglimit > $annualbalance)  {

                echo '<p><font color="red" size="-1">Annual spending limit exceed annual balance</font></p>';
                            
            }
            else {

                function gettotal($txtcost){
                    $totalspendinglimit = $txtcost++;
                    echo $totalspendinglimit;
                }
                gettotal($txtcost);

                function getbalance($annualspendinglimit,$totalspendinglimit){
                    $annualbalance = $annualspendinglimit - $totalspendinglimit;
                    echo $annualbalance;}
                getbalance($annualspendinglimit,$totalspendinglimit);

                $sqltreatment = "INSERT INTO treatment(nostaf, nosiri, date, panelcode, cost) 
                    values ('$ids', '$nosiri_new', '$_POST[txtdate]','$_POST[txtpanelcode]', '$_POST[txtcost]')";
                mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqltreatment);

                header("location: rekod_staf2.php?nostaf=$ids");
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Front end code for totalspendinglimit,annualspendinglimit and annualbalance

```
<td width="141"><font face="Tahoma">Total spend</font></td>
          <td width="173"><font face="Tahoma"><strong>RM <font face="Tahoma"> 
            <? $totalspendinglimit; ?>
            </font></strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#0099FF"> 
          <td><font face="Tahoma">&nbsp;Limit Spend</font></td>
          <td class="style71"><strong><font face="Tahoma">RM 
            <?=$r['annualspendinglimit']?>
            </font></strong></td>
          <td class="style71"><font face="Tahoma">Total balance</font></td>
          <td class="style71"><font color="#FF0000" face="Tahoma"><strong>RM 
            <? $annualbalance;
            ?>
            </strong></font></td>
```

Comment: Don't put function definitions inside `if/else`, put them at top-level.

Comment: Why do you even need to define those functions? Just put the calculations directly in the `else` block.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection due to the use of user supplied data directly in the sql command. Use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead

Comment: The variables you're assigning are local to the functions, you can't access them in other functions.

Comment: Where do you set `$txtcost`?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Do you get an error, or is your result wrong or anything different?  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the `$totalspendinglimit` locally within the `gettotal()` function, so it can't be accessed in `getbalance()`. Get rid of those functions and just assign the variables directly in the top-level code.

`$totalspendinglimit = $txtcost++;` increments `$txtcost`, but sets `$totalspendinglimit` to the value *before* it was incremented. Since you never use `$txtcost` after that, the increment is useless. I assume you actually want to set `$totalspendinglimit` to the incremented value, so you should just use `$txtcost + 1`. You also never assigned `$txtcost`, I assume below that you meant `$_POST['txtcost']`.

Use a prepared statement rather than substituting variables directly into the SQL, to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php               
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))    
{
    if(empty($_POST['txtdate']))
    {
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="-1">Fill in date</font></p>';
    } elseif(empty($_POST['txtcost'])){
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="-1">Fill in cost</font></p>';
    } elseif($annualspendinglimit > $annualbalance)  {
        echo '<p><font color="red" size="-1">Annual spending limit exceed annual balance</font></p>';
    } else {
        $totalspendinglimit = $_POST['txtcost'] + 1;
        echo $totalspendinglimit;

        $annualbalance = $annualspendinglimit - $totalspendinglimit;
        echo $annualbalance;

        $sqltreatment = "INSERT INTO treatment(nostaf, nosiri, date, panelcode, cost) 
                    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqltreatment);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $ids, $nosiri_new, $_POST['txtdate'], $_POST['txtpanelcode'], $_POST['txtcost']);
        $stmt->execute();

        header("location: rekod_staf2.php?nostaf=$ids");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I already applied this code and it successfully insert into database but does not display total spending limit and annual balance.

Comment: You have `elseif ($annualspendinglimit > $annualbalance)` before you assign to those variables. I wasn't sure what you were trying to do there, I assumed they were set in code before this block.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that your functions `return` a value rather than simply echoing back - you assign the returned value to a variable which you can use elsewhere ( in this case both for display and as input parameter to the next function )

Certain assumptions have to be made with the code you posted as there are several missing variables - they appear but nowhere are they defined in the code you shared.

Also, as per the comment above and as detailed in the answer from @Barmar - your code is vulnerable to SQL injection which could potentially cause huge damage to your site and might reveal very sensitive information. Investigate [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and use them whenever you are dealing with user supplied input.

```
<?php
    function getbalance($asl,$tsl){
        return $asl - $tsl;
    }
    function gettotal($tc){
        $tc++;
        return $tc;
    }

    $errors=array();
    
    /*
        where are $annualspendinglimit, $annualbalance, $ids and $nosiri_new defined?
    */

    if( isset(
        $_POST['Submit'],
        $_POST['txtdate'],
        $_POST['txtcost'],
        $_POST['txtpanelcode']
    ) ){
    
        if( empty( $_POST['txtdate'] ) )$errors[]='Fill in date';
        if( empty( $_POST['txtcost'] ) )$errors[]='Fill in cost';
        if( $annualspendinglimit > $annualbalance )$errors[]='Annual spending limit exceed annual balance';

        
        
        if( empty( $errors ){
        
            $txtdate=$_POST['txtdate'];
            $txtcode=$_POST['txtpanelcode'];
            $txtcost=$_POST['txtcost'];
        
        
            $totalspendinglimit=gettotal( $txtcost );
            $annualbalance=getbalance( $annualspendinglimit, $totalspendinglimit );
            
            
            printf('<div>Total Spending Limit: %s, Annual Balance: %s</div>', $totalspendinglimit, $annualbalance );
            
            
            
            $sql='INSERT INTO `treatment`
                    ( `nostaf`, `nosiri`, `date`, `panelcode`, `cost` )
                  VALUES
                    (?,?,?,?,?)';
                
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$ids,$nosiri_new,$txtdate,$txtcode,$txtcost);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
                
                
            exit( header("Location: rekod_staf2.php?nostaf=$ids") );
            
        }else{
            foreach( $errors as $error )printf('<p style="color:red;size:smaller">%s</p>',$error);
        }
    }


?>
```